# unable to start the rails server without showing any error it got abored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I did `brew update`, without any errors all the brew libraries got updated.

After then when I start the rails server with any error it got aborted.

```
project_path git:(develop) ✗ bundle exec rails server -p 4000 -b 0.0.0.0 -u thin 
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 6.1.3.2 application starting in development http://0.0.0.0:4000
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
[1]    36965 abort      bundle exec rails server -p 4000 -b 0.0.0.0 -u thin
```

My Environment

OS - Mac 13.5.2

ruby - 2.7.2

rails - 6.1.3.2

How to check the crash or error logs due to which reason server was abored?.

Answer (score 0):

In our application we are using ruby-odbc gem, depend on unixodbc.

After verifying the OS crash report, unixodbc latest version 2.3.12 is not support the ruby version 2.7.2.

Downgraded the unixodbc to 2.3.8 version and uninstall and install the ruby-odbc gem issue is resolved